# Каст с указанием типа строкой

Tags: php

```
$value = '123';
$type = 'int';
$result = ($type)$value;
```

Как мне сделать такую штуку? То есть у меня есть тип (из простых: строка, число и т.п.) строкой и значение которое надо в него скастить. Или это только свитчем проходить вручную?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

читаем [документацию](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.settype.php)

> ```
>  settype ( mixed &$var , string $type ) : bool
> ```
>
> Присваивает переменной `var` тип `type`.
>    Допустимыми значениями параметра type являются:
>     - "boolean" или "bool"
>     - "integer" или "int"
>     - "float" или "double"
>     - "string"
>     - "array"
>     - "object"
>     - "null"

а также в целом про [Манипуляции с типами](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting)

Comment: О! Именно об этом я и спрашивал. Я просто не знал что такая функция есть, но подозревал это.